# How to change the path where node search for package.json?

Tags: node.js, require

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question but I have scheme interpreter in JavaScript I'm running it in Node.js, I have file like this:

my interpreter executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

it just execute (it's part of the code, run just evaluate scheme code):

```
// parse return options and props and in _ array free args
const options = parse_options(process.argv.slice(2));
if (options.c) {
    boostrap().then(function() {
        run(options.c, env).then(print);
    });
} else if (options._.length === 1) {
   fs.readFile(options._[0], function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            boostrap().then(function() {
                // ignore shebang
                return run(data.toString().replace(/^#!.*\n/, ''), env);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

my scheme code in /home/kuba/projects/jcubic/gtk-lips/run.scm

```
#!/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/lips/bin/lips.js

(display lips.version)
(define gi (require "node-gtk"))
```

this is for testing I've tried to install node-gtk in gtk-lips directory and try to use it. But it can't find it, so basically what I need is to change the path of node require to use path of the source file run.scm not my executable lips.js, if I installed node-gtk on jcubic/lips/ it works, I want to have it in gtk-lips directory.

I've tried to set path to `require("/home/kuba/projects/jcubic/gtk-lips/node_modules/" + name")`; is this the only way?

It works, but one problem with this approach, is that it will not find node_module, if I create directory in gtk-lips/foo/ and try to run in that directory.

My code so far:

```
if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    global_env.set('require', doc(function(module) {
        typecheck('require.resolve', module, 'string');
        module = module.valueOf();
        var root = process.cwd() + '/';
        if (!module.match(/^\s*\./)) { // just in case if it's "   ./"
            root += "node_modules/";
        }
        return require(root + module);
    }, `(require module)

        Function to be used inside Node.js to import the module.`));
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Do I need to search for first node_module in tree like Node or is there some mechanism were you be able to change where node search for packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented reverse search algorithm:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function reversseFind(dir, fn) {
    var parts = dir.split(path.sep).filter(Boolean);
    for (var i=parts.length; i--;) {
        var p = path.join('/', ...parts.slice(0, i));
        if (fn(p)) {
            return p;
        }
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function nodeModuleFind(dir) {
    return reversseFind(dir, function(dir) {
        return fs.existsSync(path.join(dir, 'node_modules'));
    });
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');

   global_env.set('require', doc(function(module) {
        typecheck('require.resolve', module, 'string');
        module = module.valueOf();
        var root = process.cwd();
        if (module.match(/^\s*\./)) {
            return require(path.join(root, module));
        } else {
            var dir = nodeModuleFind(root);
            if (dir) {
                // local module
                return require(path.join(dir, "node_modules", module));
            } else {
                // global module
                return require(module);
            }
        }
    }, `(require module)

        Function to be used inside Node.js to import the module.`));
}
```